# How to rank and list first 10 order_ids for each user_id who ordered a product?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
This is the A/B Experiment table with 4 columns:
    1. user_id
    2. experiment_id
    3. experiment_date
    4. experiment_type (values are either: test or control - group)

This is the Order table with 3 columns:
    1. user_id
    2. order_sku 
    3. order_date
```

**I am trying to list the top 10 user_ids who ordered a product and rank it for each experiment_id.**

```
The output Table should look like this:
1. experiment_id
2. Rank
3. user_id
4. experiment_type
5. experiment_date
```

How would I do that in mySQL? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: which database you use?

Comment: @MohitKumar sorry, I am using mySQL :)

Comment: Which version of mysql? It’s relevant because recent versions have window functions.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the ranking.

Answer (score 1):

you use `RANK()` with `INNER JOIN`

```
select RANK() as Rank , experiment_id , user_id , experiment_type , experiment_date 
from experiment e 
inner join order o 
where e.user_id=o.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

```
SELECT e.*, r.rank FROM `Experiment` e
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT c.user_id, c.rank FROM
    (SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) as rank FROM `Order` GROUP BY user_id) c
  ORDER BY c.rank DESC LIMIT 10
  ) r ON e.user_id = r.user_id
```